# Using foreach loop breaks

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I'm new to WordPress, and I'm having an issue with "The Loop."
I have 2 custom post type named 'book' and 'author'
.in author post type I have custom filed checkbox which can choose between author and translator.
also in book post type I have 2 metaboxs which user must choose the name of author and translator from those.
all metabox and custom post type work well but when I want to call them and use the values of each meta-box I have problem.
my code can read author values well, but translator values just show the last value of author and I cant' figure out why this happen ? 
I think foreach is the problem. but I don't know how can I solve it.
here is my code for single-book.php

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'book'); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
// for reading author which choose from cheak box in each book pages.
    $post_id = get_the_ID(); 
    $key = 'save-author-to-book';
    $key2='save-trans-to-book';
    $vals=get_post_meta($post_id, $key2, true);
    $values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    ?>
    echo '<h4 class="text-right color-style"> نویسنده : ';
    foreach($values as $value){
        $author=get_post($value);
        echo '<a href="'.
        get_post_permalink($value).'" target="_blank">'.
        $author->post_title .'</a> ، ' ;}
    echo '</h4>';

    echo '<h4 class="text-right color-style"> مترجم : ';
        foreach($vals as $val){
        $trans=get_post($val);
        echo '<a href="'.
        get_post_permalink($val).'" target="_blank">'.
        $author->post_title.'</a>، ';}

    echo '</h4>';
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: the second 'foreach' loop should have this line: `$trans->post_title.'</a>، ';}` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is with `$vals=get_post_meta($post_id, $key2, true);`

If you check the codex, the last parameter for [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) is whether to return a single value or array of values. You have set it to `true` which means return only one value.

Try it with `false` (the default) it should work.

Comment: it must be true because one book may have more than one translator and it return array then.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment bynicolas answer, but I agree with him.
If I understood correctly your issue, it is because your are using `true` at the end of:

```
$vals=get_post_meta($post_id, $key2, true);
$values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );
```

When you use true, from the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

> **$single** (bool) (Optional) Whether to return a single value.
>
> **Return** (mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.

You can't `foreach` a `string`, only `arrays`, hence why if you don't use `false` instead, your code won't work.

Or, if you only want the first result of the `post_meta`, keep using `true`, but then why do you use the foreach? You dont need it, you can simply use this:

```
if($value != '') {
    $author=get_post($value);
    echo '<a href="'.get_post_permalink($value).'" target="_blank">'.$author->post_title .'</a> ، ' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful on line 11:

```
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    ?>
    echo '<h4 class="text-right color-style"> نویسنده : ';
```

Do you use exactly this code? Because you close the PHP syntax exactly after getting the `$feat_image` and after that, the code continues with PHP syntax like `echo`.

I believe that the code breaks because of that little `?>` and the first loop never ends.

Comment: no I didn't use exactly this code I close php after echo part :D I wrote it wrong here.